# WPF Drag drop outside window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am looking for some sample code which can show how to drag outside Application window.

In my Application, I have a Image. I want User to drag this image and drop it on some other

Application. Also at the time of drag, I want to show the crosshair like mouse icon. Can you

please provide some sample code or link on how to do this?

Comment: I'm sure this can be found with search... It is a common task.. DragDropHelper and DoDragDrop I believe it is.